# Finding the min of a dictionary value in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, min

I need to find the `min` of a dictionary second element without using the `min()` function in python. Need to be a loop.

For example, my `dictionary` is

```
sol = {"shape1":[250, 300, 280], "shape2":[46, 70, 5], 
       "shape3":[147, 12, 150], "shape4":[107, 10, 108]}
```

The output that I should get is  **shape2**, Since the first value is lower then the other shape first value.

Any help would be apricated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One liner using `sorted` by dict values

```
sol= {"shape1":[250, 300, 280], 
    "shape2":[46, 70, 5], 
    "shape3":[147, 12, 150], 
    "shape4":[107, 10, 108]}

[(k) for k, v in sorted(sol.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][0])][0] # 'shape2'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sol = {"shape1":[250, 300, 280], "shape2":[46, 70, 5], "shape3":[147, 12, 150], "shape4":[107, 10, 108]}

smallest_shape = ""
smallest_value = 0
for i, pair in enumerate(sol.items()):
    if i == 0 or pair[1][0] < smallest_value:
        smallest_shape = pair[0]
        smallest_value = pair[1][0]

print(smallest_shape)
```